# Which is correct: "have been completed" or "are completed"

Tags: present-perfect, participial-adjectives

Part of my work includes making modifications to a software application.

After making the requested modifications, I typically send an email to those in charge of user acceptance testing, informing them that they should log in to the UAT system to check the work.

In these emails I often write something like this:

> The requested modifications have been completed.

But sometimes I may instead write the sentence like this:

> The requested modifications are completed.

Are these both correct English? If not, please explain why.

Comment: Yes you can use the below one and i am strongly Recommended to use this *'Requested modifications have been completed."*

Comment: How about finished, accomplished or done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The requested modifications **have been completed**.

is better, because you are referring to a continuing action (you finished writing the code, but it will get tested next).

Put into context:

> The requested modifications have been completed. You may now begin your testing process.

In this example:

> The requested modifications **are completed**.

*are* refers to the current state, but *completed* is past tense. I won't say people don't write it this way, but it would be better to write:

> The requested modifications **are complete**.

As a simple statement of fact this is fine.